# How to use BaseMap with chaco plots

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, chaco

I had developed scatter and lasso selection plots with Chaco. Now, I need to embed a BaseMap [with few markers on a map] onto the plot area side by side.

I created a BaseMap and tried to add to the traits_view; but it is failing with errors.

Please give me some pointers to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Chaco and matplotlib are completely different tools. Basemap has been built on top of matplotlib so it is not possible to add a Basemap map on a Chaco plot.

I'm afraid I couldn't find any mapping layer to go with Chaco. Is there a reason you cannot use matplotlib for you plot?